# How to Hide Woocommerce email notification field on admin CP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm facing a problem with my Woocemmerce mod and I would be glad if someone could help me.

my doubt is: how can I hide email at Woo setting/email tab? I would like to hide email from 3 specific fields.

[image]

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom javascript file with the below code

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
            var pattern = /^([a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+(\.[a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+)*|"((([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7e\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))*(([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?")@(([a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.)+([a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.?$/i;
            return pattern.test(emailAddress);
        }
        var recipients= document.getElementsByClassName('wc-email-settings-table-recipient');
        for(var i=0;i<recipients.length;i++){
            if(isValidEmailAddress(recipients[i].innerText)){
                recipients[i].innerText='This is hidden';// do what you want, fex. you can change the style instead of this
            }
        }
    });
```

and enqueue the created js file on the admin page by applying below code into your *functions.php* file.

```
function my_enqueue() {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/myscript.js' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

also please note that the class name `wc-email-settings-table-recipient` may change for different versions of wooCommerce plugin.

Hope this helps.